# How to clear struct or create new one each time it called?

Tags: c++, struct

I have the following struct:

```
const int max_stu= 100;
const int max_name =100;
const int max_add=100;

struct stu{
      int id;
      char name[max_name];
      char addr[max_add];
};

stu student[max_stu];
```

One of my friends already give me this code

```
struct stu{
     int id;
     char name[max_name];
     char addr[max_add];
void  remove(stu temp){
        temp.id= 0;
        temp.name= "";
        temp.addr= "";

}

for (int i=0;i < max_stu; i++){
    stu.remove(student[i]);
}
```

but it have problem in this part

```
temp.name= "";
```

because of the type of char and

```
max_name=100
```

and on this part

```
stu.remove(student[i]);
```

because its not a class. How can I fix this?

Comment: name[max_name] and  addr[max_add] are not assignable. You better use std::string or otherwise some of strcpy(...) functions

Comment: Start from scratch, and this time use `std::vector` and `std::string`.

Comment: it about 1500 line programming unfourtunetly i cant do that . .
any idea to build a new stu student[max_stu]; each time?

Comment: wwwow ! 
actually i found a idea . .
i can use stu student[k][max_stu];
this straction and each time ++k and save it

Comment: A struct is like a class where all methods and fields are public. Your friend's help is a little misleading. Investigate how something like student[i].remove() would work, and think more about what is necessary to reset the elements in an array.

Comment: First, think about whether `remove` should be a member function or a normal function. Second, think about what's the meaning of clearing a `char` array. If you only use it as a C-style string, you only need to set the first element to be `'\0'`.